# Change view lose data - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, view, viewmodel

hi I'm try to develop Datalogger, so i create a menu, to Switch de Options i decided to use DataTemplates and different ViewModels.
[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9ijI.png)

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="GraficoVtemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:GraficoVM}">
        <view:GraficoV DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListaVtemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ListaVM}">
        <view:ListaV DataContext="{Binding }"/>
    </DataTemplate>
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

This is how i change the datacontext;

XAML.CS

```
private void Novoteste_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new NovoTesteVM();
    }

    private void Lista_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new ListaVM();
    }
```

This is the files that i have, the models are empty and the viewsmodals have some controles.[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgRJF.png)

The problem is that when I change the menu, the content of the previous menu is not saved, that is when I select the menu "lista" and fill in a datagrid, and I go to another menu when I select again the menu "lista" the data are lost.I do not know what I need to add, or change so that the data is not lost

Thanks you for the explanation!

Edit 1:

MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
private void Novoteste_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = NovoTesteVM.NovoTesteViewModel;            
    }


    private void Grafico_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = GraficoVM.Grafico;
    }
```

NovoTesteVM.cs

```
 public class NovoTesteVM
{

    private static NovoTesteVM novoTesteViewModel;
    public static NovoTesteVM NovoTesteViewModel
    {
        get
        {                
           novoTesteViewModel = novoTesteViewModel ?? new NovoTesteVM();

            return novoTesteViewModel;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create container properties to keep the wiewmodel for corresponding views. It's loosing data because you are initializing new object on click.

Sample code -

```
    private NovoTesteVM novoTesteViewModel;
    public NovoTesteVM NovoTesteViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            novoTesteViewModel = novoTesteViewModel ?? new NovoTesteViewModel();
            return novoTesteViewModel;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think I realized, the sample code i add to NovotesteVm and when I click only call NovoTesteVM() that it ?

Comment: Instead of `new NovoTesteVM();`, do ` DataContext = NovoTesteViewModel;`. You need to have this property in class before using it.

Comment: I already made the changes but the data is lost in the same. what i need to do more?